# jquery .val remove spaced text

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

ok, so i have a select items in which the option comes from the database:

```
<select id="subject_code" name="subject_code">;
<?php
    $stmt = $database->prepare('SELECT subject_code, subject_name FROM subject_schedule');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $subj_code = $row['subject_code'];
        $subj_name = $row['subject_name'];
        echo "<option value=" . $subj_name . ">" . $subj_code . "</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

an input box where the selected item should put its value:

```
<input id="subject_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Subject Name" name="time">
```

and a script where it will do the job:

```
$("#subject_code").on('change',function(){
  //get selected option
  var option = $(":selected",this);

  //get its value
  var value = option.val();

  //get input box
  var input = $("#subject_name")[0];

  // set value and disable input
  input.value = value;
});
```

the problem is whenever i select a value in which it has spaces on them, the input box only display the first word from the database.
example:

preferred output:

```
subject code: ENG111
subject name: Communication Arts 1
```

current output

```
subject code: ENG111
subject name: Communication
```

Comment: Does `console.log(value)` show entire string with spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with quotes:

Replace this:

```
echo "<option value=" . $subj_name . ">" . $subj_code . "</option>";
```

With this:

```
echo "<option value='" . $subj_name . "'>" . $subj_code . "</option>";
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5EvL/)